# What is the difference between using int() and int(float()) when reading through a file line by line to create a DataFrame?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, file-io

When I run my code I get "VAlueError: could not convert string to float: '5\t1\t1\t1\t2\t1\t3\t1\t1\t1' ". I've tried using just (int(num[0])) but it said invalid literal for int() with base 10... and so on. Now I have no clue how to fix this error..

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

def readLabels(fileName):

with open("winsonsin labels.txt") as f:
    
    labels = f.read().split(',')

    return labels

def readData(fileName, labels):

with open("wisconsin.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    
    data = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]
    print(data)
    
    dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data , labels)
    
    return(dataFrame)

def graph(data, labels):
figure = px.parallel_coordinates(data_frame = data,
                                 color= 'class',
                                 dimensions = labels[:-1])
figure.show()
   
readLabels("wisonsin labels.txt")
labels = readLabels("wisonsin labels.txt")
readData("wisconson.txt", labels )
data = readData("wisconson.txt", labels )
graph(data, labels)
```

sample of the txt file:
there's many columns with 10 rows each

```
5   1   1   1   2   1   3   1   1   1
5   4   4   5   7   10  3   2   1   1
3   1   1   1   2   2   3   1   1   1
```

wisonsin labels txt file:
radius,texture,perimeter,area,smoothness,compactness,concavity,concave_points,symmetry,class

Comment: You can probably split with tabs. `nums = [[float(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]`

Comment: and seems like you have 10 columns not rows

Comment: @Larry the Llama when I do this, I still get the same ValueError

Comment: The core problem you have in your code is using `splitlines` when you want `split`. The `splitlines` method only splits on newlines, not any whitespace like `split` does (by default).

Comment: I'd also note that the title of this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the core issue. To answer the title's question, `int(float(some_string))` accepts strings like `1.23`, which it truncates to `1`. Just `int(x)` will raise an exception because decimal points are not valid in integers.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Larry the Llama` commnet talked about it well.

I've made the codes a bit more readable.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


def readLabels(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        labels = f.read().split(',')
        print(len(labels))
        return labels


def readData(fileName, labels):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        data = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]
        print(data)

        dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=labels)

        return (dataFrame)


def graph(data, labels):
    figure = px.parallel_coordinates(data_frame=data,
                                     color='class',
                                     dimensions=labels[:-1])

    figure.show()


readLabels("wisonsin labels.txt")
labels = readLabels("wisonsin labels.txt")
readData("wisconson.txt", labels)
data = readData("wisconson.txt", labels)
graph(data, labels)
```

here is output on my local, maybe your library has a problem, it is better to reinstall all. and re-execute it
[image]

Comment: when I do this I still get the same ValueError

Comment: I changed the `float` to `int` in the code. Would you like to try this?

Comment: okay, I tried this but it crashes at "num[0] = (int(float(num[0])))" and I get a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5\t1\t1\t1\t2\t1\t3\t1\t1\t1'

Comment: Looks like you're still using the wrong old code.
 I edited the example more, check it out

Comment: So i've updated the code on my computer to what you said and now I have a ValueError saying "Shape of passed values is (683, 10), indices imply (10, 10)". What does this mean?

Comment: I can't know without seeing the full code you run.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the code on here because I can't have chats on here yet

Comment: please add `winsonsin labels.txt`

Comment: The second input value of the DataFrame is the index. I think you put the column value here. I edited that part.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't show a graph? Just all the nums from wisonsin labels txt file

Comment: i'm doing well
There seems to be a problem with your data or the version of the library installed on your PC. Check it

Comment: ohh, okay okay. Thank you so much!

Comment: or check your browser, there is a result.